How does one cite the Mishnah?
I need to cite Mishnah 1 of Chapter 8 of Tractate Chullin in a paper. What is the proper format? I believe it is simply "Chullin 8:1"; is that correct? Do I need to mention that it is from Seder Kodashim?

Is the paper for a journal? Does the journal use MLA formatting? APA? Something else? This is a question for your editor/evaluator. We can't possibly know what you need to do

@DoubleAA It's a college class paper, and we use Turabian formatting. I checked in Turabian's Manual for Writers, and did not find anything about citing the Mishnah, only that religious works in general are to be cited "in footnotes, endnotes, or parenthetical notes." The only religious work for which it gives specific instructions is the Bible.

https://www.typecite.com/learn/mla/how-to-cite-religious-works-in-mla/

Specify which edition, e.g. https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Chullin?tab=versions; then you can simply say Mishna Chulin 8:1. Those who know where to look can find it with that; and for those who can't -- telling them it's in Kodashim won't help.

@Shalom Thank you! It's the version translated by Rabbi Philip Blackman; I'm quoting from a print edition in my college's library, and this version is not available on Sefaria. This is what I have for now; does it look good? "Mishnah Chullin 8:1, trans. by Rabbi Philip Blackman."

Not sure this is a question about Judaism.
